# What's A Field Group?

Tags: spfield

I need to create a field programatically, but the field has a required "Group" property. What is this property? What does it do/change? and what's a sensible value? MSDN as usual, failed to enlighten me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Group property is a string, it's used to Group fields on the Site Columns page.

If you do this through the UI it provides a default of "Custom Columns".

Typically I use something descriptive for the particular customer and project, e.g. "{Customer}: {Project}"

Answer (score 1):

It defines where it shows up in Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Columns if I recall correctly.